# Promise.all() resolving, but it shouldn't (node.js)

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise

I'm trying something like this right now in node.js:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec
var write = require('fs-writefile-promise')

function run() {
    var myArray = [];   
    var execs = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        (function(cntr) {
            write('file-' + i + '.txt', someString)
            .then(function (filename) {
                execs.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    exec('cat ' + 'file-' + cntr + '.cnf', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
                        console.log(cntr + ' ' + stdout);
                        if (stdout.search(/\bsomeString\b/) > -1) {
                            myArray.push(cntr);
                            resolve();
                        } 
                        else {
                            resolve();
                        }   
                    })
                }))
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
        })(i);
    }
    return Promise.all(execs).then(function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            resolve(myArray);
        }) 
    })
}

run().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

As you can see, I'm creating multiple Promises that run `exec()` and each one of them resolves when `exec()` finishes. 
Then I'm waiting for every Promise to resolve in `Promise.all(execs)` to return `myArray` as a Promise. Yet, when I execute my `run()` function at the end, it is returning an empty array. I guess this has something to do with `Promise.all()` as it resolves even if some Promises in `execs` haven't resolved yet, but I'm not sure, thats why I really need some help here. Does anyone know where I'm making a mistake in code?

Thank you very much in advance!

**#EDIT 1**

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec
var write = require('fs-writefile-promise')

function run() {
    var myArray = [];   
    var execs = [];

    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        (function(cntr) {
            return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                fs.writeFile('file-' + i + '.txt', someString, (err) => {
                    if (err) {
                        reject();
                    }
                    else {
                        resolve();
                    }
                });
            })
            .then(function (filename) {
                execs.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    exec('cat ' + 'file-' + cntr + '.cnf', function(error, stdout, stderr) {
                        console.log(cntr + ' ' + stdout);
                        if (stdout.search(/\bsomeString\b/) > -1) {
                            myArray.push(cntr);
                            resolve();
                        } 
                        else {
                            resolve();
                        }   
                    })
                }))
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.error(err);
            });
        })(i);
    }
    return Promise.all(execs).then(function() {
        return new Promise(function(resolve) {
            resolve(myArray);
        }) 
    })
}

run().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Code is plagued with promise constructor anti-pattern. You need to learn how asynchronous code works, when things happen, and try again.

Comment: You're asynchronously pushing to `execs`, and the array is always empty at the point of calling `Promise.all`. Push the promises for the values immediately to that array.

Comment: @Bergi What do you mean by pushing the promises immediately?

Comment: Any function inside a `.then()` runs *later*, which means your `execs.push` happens *after* `Promise.all(execs)`, which means you're doing `Promise.all([])` effectively. As Bergi says, push the "write" promises on the execs array (really the whole promise chain) instead. Right now you're returning those 7 promises in the loop to nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

There are numerous issues with both your attempts.  The issue with the first attempt is that you're populating the execs array after an asynchronous operation so it has nothing in it when you actually pass the array to `Promise.all()`, thus `Promise.all()` has nothing to wait for.

In addition, you're not just using promises that are already created, thus you end up making way more promises than needed.

In general, it is best to "promisify" your async operations once outside of your main logic and then have all your logic be promise driven rather than mixing and matching promises with plain callbacks.  Here's a version that attempts to fix those issues:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec
var write = require('fs-writefile-promise')

// make promisified version of exec
function execP(file, options) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        exec(file, options, function(err, stdout, stderr) {
            if (err) return resolve(err);
            resolve({stdout: stdout, stderr: stderr});
        });
    });
}

function run() {
    var promises = [];
    for (var i = 1; i <= 7; i++) {
        promises.push(write('file-' + i + '.txt', someString).then(function(filename) {
            return execP(filename);
        }));
    }
    return Promise.all(promises).then(function(results) {
        // results is an array of {stdout: xxx, stderr: yyy} objects
        // process those results into a new array of just indexes
        var final = [];
        results.forEach(function(data, index) {
            if (data.stdout.search(/\bsomeString\b/) > -1) {
                final.push(index);
            }
        });
        return final;
    });
}

run().then(function(results) {
    // array of indexes that contained the desired search string
}, function(err) {
    // process error here
});
```

Note: This runs all your exec operations in parallel which is what your original code did.  If you want to run them sequentially, that could be done too, but would require some tweaks.

Answer (score 1):

As `write` is asynchronous, the program at this stage is passing back to the main thread and that's going straight through to your promise.all and returning that before execs has been loaded.

I suggest you create a function that returns a promise of *both* a file save followed by exec.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I edited my code as you can see in **Edit 1** in my original post. I replaced the `write()` function with a new Promise in which I write the file. Yet, this is still not working, but it should regarding to the documentation.